# Can't locate CSS in a wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm editing a wordpress theme and I can't find CSS file, when I try to inspect the element on my browser, it says the location of CSS is located in wp-content/cache/minify/000000 - and the files located there are: css.gzip.old, css.old and some .js files. 
It's the first time I encountered with these files in wordpress. 
I don't have any idea what to do. Because when I try to find the code in these files I can't find it.
(It's not my theme, I just need to fix some elements in the CSS, I also think it's made on bootstrap)

Thank you.

Comment: You probably have the `W3 Total Cache` plugin installed, try disabling it

Comment: Is it minified with a plugin?

Comment: Dear @Urdz your css is minified, but don't worry, you still can modify your theme CSS and rebuild the minify cache again by clearing it through the cache plugin settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WordPress website might have any Cache related plugin like "WP Super Cache" or "W3 Total Cache" etc.

first you should clear cache from the settings of these plugins.
then you should deactivate these plugins.

if you need to edit or modify your theme .CSS , you can do it easily through going to: Appearance => Editor => here you will see the Style.css file of your theme. you can edit it and save it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this plugin. I would go under Appearance -> Editor, but the style.css is empty. I disabled WP total Cache now the direction is different and it sends me to: /www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/js and there are .js files again.

Comment: which theme you are using , some WordPress theme do not have their stylesheet in style.css, their stylesheet files in this case located into `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME-FOLDER-NAME/css/` directory. do you have ftp access of your website. may you provide the url of your website?

Comment: It's a custom made theme for a company, and I got the job to fix CSS some elements. It's not from wordpress themes.

There are .js files: bootstrap.js, functions.js, ie.js, retina.js, sweet-alert.js, etc.

Comment: Please disable all cache related plugin, then provide the URL to me, so i can help you locate your Stylesheet.

Comment: There are also plugins: WP Clean Up and WP REST API. Should I disable them too?

Comment: it would be better if you can disable all of them for only 10 minutes. and let me know, also if you like you can do it yourself with the help of Browser Developer tools=> inspector

Comment: Okay, I will let you know what is happening. Also if I won't be able to locate my CSS I will give you the URL, if that's okay.

Comment: also, please check if you are using a child theme, in that case , you need to locate your parent theme css file.

Comment: Okay, I disabled all of the plugins. Everything is the same. I tried to modify some settings in Preformance - Minify and stuff like that and nothing changed.

Comment: Please provide following: [1] Name of your theme [2] your Website URL

Comment: thanks, i have checked it your CSS files are located inside `/wp-content/themes/ferfl/inc/css/` directory. mainly `template.css` and `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to open this folder before but I couldn't do it. When I try to open it says: Failure retrieving contents of directory /www/wp-content/themes/ferfl/inc/css

Comment: This directory seems to be write protected, you need to modify its Permission setting, you can do it easily via FTP client like Filezilla, you can also do it via CPanel too. take google help or check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi0dl0MbkWw, once you modify the file, change its permission to original settings, it is for security purpose.

Comment: Dear @Urdz I am very happy to know that, if it is possible, please mark it as your answer, so others too can take some help.

Comment: what do you mean by HTML stuff? If you like to change any Page, Post of your WordPress website, you just need to edit your pages.

Comment: It's okay. I found everything. Thank you.